# Failure when initializing PouchDB

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

Here is my stack trace when attempting to launch my api side of my react - web app.

I have ran into this error multiple times but never seem to be able to fix it when it comes up again!

```
/Users/joshua_paulsen/Desktop/Jump-In-Final/api/node_modules/pouchdb-core/lib/index.js:1285
    throw new Error('Invalid Adapter: ' + opts.adapter);
    ^

Error: Invalid Adapter: undefined
    at new PouchDB (/Users/joshua_paulsen/Desktop/Jump-In-Final/api/node_modules/pouchdb-core/lib/index.js:1285:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joshua_paulsen/Desktop/Jump-In-Final/api/dal.js:18:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joshua_paulsen/Desktop/Jump-In-Final/api/routes/workouts/index.js:8:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had my db defined like this - const db = new PouchDB(
  `${process.env.COUCH_HOSTNAME}${process.env.COUCH_DBNAME}`
)

the fix ended up being changing it to this.

- var pouch = new PouchDB(`${process.env.COUCH_DBNAME}`, { adapter: "http" })